# Surface of Revoution

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Which generating circles ($x=constant$) appear to be geodesics? Why ?

There is a hint: Imaging laying a ribbon on the surface. 
[image] 
I could not find a way to approach this problem. I looked up and I found a way of using calculus to prove that which is not what I want. This course all about Geometry so I have to convince myself what is the answer for that. Help is really appreciate it . Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know what definitions/results you have at your disposal. But think about going along the circles at constant speed; when will the perceived acceleration vector be $0$ (i.e., the actual acceleration normal to the surface)?

Comment: inside the surface ?

Comment: I don't understand. Also, when you say the course is "all about geometry," how is geodesic defined?

Comment: geodesic is a generalization of the notion of a "straight line" to "curved spaces"